# Vector space with multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

A vector space is a commutative group and I am wondering if it can be extended to be a ring by defining a multiplication. I tried $v \cdot w = (v_1 w_1, ..., v_nw_n)$ componentwise but then inverses aren't unique. Is it possible to construct a multiplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction you described is a perfectly fine way to define a multiplication operation on a vector space, which is just viewing the vector space as the ring product of $n$ copies of the field.

There are other ways too, but they are not always possible for every $n$. Here's what I mean: suppose $n=k^2$. Then you can just rewrite the vectors as $k\times k$ matrices, and then you have multiplication given by matrix multiplication. That would be an entirely different multiplication than the one you proposed.

There are still more ways that a vector space can have a multiplication, but there are not a lot that work for generic vector spaces (the coordinatewise product above is an exception.) The study of vector spaces that are rings is just the study of [algebras over fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field).

---

I think there is another construction you should be interested in, but it is not exactly what you're asking for. This is purely for your information.

The [tensor algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra) $T(V)$ of a vector space $V$ is "the biggest algebra generated by $V$". In some sense this means it is a ring that contains $V$ and doesn't contain superfluous stuff, and that every other algebra like that is a quotient of it.

This produces a multiplication on a much larger set ($T(V)$) and when you multiply things in $V$ toegether, you do not generally get something back in $V$, so it is not really a multiplication on $V$. Still, this is a rather interesting thing to study. The tensor algebra itself, and several quotients of it (like the [symmetric algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra), the [exterior algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), and [Clifford algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra)) are very interesting algebras.

Comment: Thank you, that's an awesome answer!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "inverses aren't unique. They are unique, if they exists. The multiplicative unit is $(1,1,\ldots, 1)$ and $v \in K^n$ has an inverse iff $v_i \ne 0$ for *all* $i$, the inverse is then given by $(v_1^{-1}, \ldots, v_n^{-1})$. The ring $K^n$ constructed is known as the direct product of $n$ copies of the ring $K$.

Comment: I meant that $(x,0, \dots)$ has the inverse $(x^{-1}, 0, \dots)$ but also $(x^{-1}, \alpha, \dots)$. Don't all elements have to have an multiplicative inverse in a ring? As you write it it seems that elements like $(x,0,...)$ don't have inverses.

Comment: I realize that when I wrote ring I meant field. Duh.